# Permissions error when posting to a group I administer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is able to post to several pages successfully, but when I try to post to a group:

```
    $page_id    = MY_GROUP_ID;
    $page_access_token = "";
    $result =  $fb->api("/me/accounts");

    $page_access_token = "";
    // loop trough all your pages and find the right one
    if( !empty($result['data']) )
    {
        foreach($result["data"] as $page)
        {
            if($page["id"] == $page_id)
            {
                $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "AN ERROR OCCURED: could not get the access_token. Please verify the page ID ".$page_id." exists.";
    }

    // set the facebook active facebook access token as the one we just fetch
    $fb->setAccessToken($page_access_token);

    // Now try to post on page's wall
    try{
        $message = array(
            'message' => "Test message",
            'description' => "Test Description",
            'link' => "http://example.org"
        );
        $result = $fb->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed','POST',$message);
        if($result){
            echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Wall...';
        }
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}else{

    $fbloginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect-uri'=>$returnurl, 'scope'=>$permissions));
    echo '<a href="'.$fbloginurl.'">Login with Facebook</a>';

}
```

I get

```
(#200) Permissions error
```

If I go here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, I can see my app and permissions it has.   I do not see anything in the list pertaining to groups.

I've logged out and was prompted to log in with the script (above), but am not being prompted to edit/add app permissions.   I cannot find any app related settings under Group Settings for the group I have.

I remember seeing the app permissions page a year ago when I first made the app, but short of deleting the current and recreating, is there a way to simply edit existing permissions to add my group to the app?  I am not seeing any group permissions when I click on the app under the app settings page (right above).

Comment: your code above doesn't mention anything about groups.

Comment: First line: `$page_id    = MY_GROUP_ID;`.  Then again I'm unsure how to form the request.  I'm reading elsewhere that posting to groups is no longer supported.